# Set up webpack to run locally on a custom domain over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, localhost, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

In order to use a module I want to integrate into my application (I am developing locally), I have to do two things:
1) Make my application run locally on HTTPS.
2) Run the application with a specific domain.

Both of these things should be pretty easy with the Webpack dev server I am using for local development, but for some reason it is not working as the documentation suggests.

My `webpack.config` file is:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/js/app.js',
  output: {
    path:'./app/js/',
    publicPath: 'https://specialurl.com/assets',
    filename:'bundle.js'
 }
```

The path I am pointing to has been added to my hosts file on my computer, so it should be just as valid as the localhost default.

And my `package.json` file has this as it's start script for the dev server:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --https",
}
```

I made these changes and then I restarted with npm start after saving. The problem is that the server is still not running on https, and when I point my browser to the new link, it just shows nothing. All documentation that I have found makes it seem like this should work, so I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: Why not just put an nginx server in front of webpack, set up with certs, and edit your hosts file to point the domain at the nginx?

Comment: Because it seems like webpack has all the capabilities needed, so I'd like to keep things streamlined if possible. If not that does seem like a good idea to try :)

Comment: Just saying - this is pretty easy with a Node server, which I prefer even in development because it is more scalable and flexible

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Solved it! Turns out it's very very easy to do with Webpack as I expected, but the documentation is a little confusing.

You simply edit your host file to contain the domain you want, and then add the following code to your `webpack.config`:

```
 devServer: {
  host: "localhost.specialurl.com",
  port: 1234,
  https: true
},
```

Run `npm start` and point your browser to https://localhost.specialurl.com:1234/webpack-dev-server and you should be all set :)

Comment: any luck getting this to work with `hot:true`? the app works on the custom domain but webpack keeps trying to open a socket.io connection to localhost:3000 instead.

Comment: how did you edit your hosts file? `127.0.0.1    localhost.specialurl.com` ?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to add `127.0.0.1 localhost.specialurl.com` to get this to work

Comment: You can also do 
`127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.specialurl.com` so that localhost also keeps working.

Comment: adding  127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.specialurl.com to my windows host file works. Another way is that if you have control of the domain you can add A record to the domain and point the localhost.specialurl.com to a IP address 127.0.0.1. For example, if you ping localhost.huawei.com it's resolved to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 4):

To make this work with Hot Module Reloading, set the `public` value to `undefined`, and then it will use the value in `host`.

```js
environment.config.devServer.public = undefined
environment.config.devServer.host = 'localhost.example.com'
environment.config.devServer.https = {
  https: true,
  hot: true,
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('ssl/localhost.example.com.key.pem')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('ssl/localhost.example.com.cert.pem')),
}
```

This is because of this line, Which ignores the specified host, if `public` is defined:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/lib/utils/createDomain.js#L16

Answer (score 0):

For those who may have fought with this as I did. I had to set `requestCert: false` while the webpack doc gives an example with `requestCert: true`:

```json
devServer: {
    host: 'mydomain.com',
    allowedHosts: 'all',
    server: {
        type: 'https',
        options: {
            key: path.join(__dirname, './file.key'),
            cert: path.join(__dirname, './file.crt'),
            requestCert: false,
        },
    },
    port: 9000
}
```