# Vue + Webpack - Specifying the server for hot reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-loader

So I have the following config file for use with webpack-dev-server:

```
'use strict'
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: [
        './src/app.js'
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'index.html',
            inject: true
        })
    ],
}
```

It works all well and good, however by default it seems to start the live reload server on http://localhost:8082. Is there a way to specify what host to use for the live reload, like say i have a custom domain defined as https://hotreload.com:3000? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191884/set-up-webpack-to-run-locally-on-a-custom-domain-over-https/31252683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `webpack.config.js` to specify [`devServer.host`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-host), [`devServer.port`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-port), and [`devServer.https`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-https). Using your example specs:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    host: 'hotreload.com',
    port: 3000,
    https: true,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the devServer.public.  It would be nice if this would take just the url path but it apparently needs the whole url:

```
devServer: {
    public: 'https://www.yoursite.com/',
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving my day.